# Trying to read a TDMS file using python but I get a "check whether the tdm_index matches the file" error

Tags: python, labview

When I run this code:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile as tf 
file = tf('myfile.tdms')
```

I get the following error:

> "Check that the tdms_index file matches the tdms data file.")
>
> ValueError: Attempted to read data segment at position 123 but did not
> find segment start header. Check that the tdms_index file matches the
> tdms data file.

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change?

Comment: Okay it seems like if I delete a file named .tdms_index it works itself out. But the .tdms_index file is created by Diadem and I need it.

Comment: The tdms_index file is a quick lookup helper file. Programs (like diadem) can read TDMS files without it an will re-generate the file if missing. See https://www.ni.com/en-nz/support/documentation/supplemental/06/the-ni-tdms-file-format.html 
TDMS files also automatically generate a complimentary *.tdms_index file. This file provides consolidated information on all the attributes and pointers in the bulk data file that drastically speeds up read access to the data on larger data sets. This index file is not required for storage or distribution and automatically regenerates